# In Python flask ,to send href link id from html to flask function ?or is there any way so i can send unique id from every href link to flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

#I am new to flask and html and created web page where there are multiple links on and it will get added in future and every link has unique file name given. whenever i click a link it should download respective name file.
#All link are generated from href attribute from html and is there any way so i could send any id or name from href attribute to python flask function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put query parameters in your links:

```
<a href="file?id=abcd">Link</a>
```

and then you can get it from the flask app like:

```
request.args.get("id") # from flask import request
```